# how to mask textbox after ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mask

I am returning values from the database after checking if it has value. If it has a value, it will be displayed in my textbox. But I want it to be masked with the format of (000-000-000-000), apparently, it is not working. But with normal input, the mask is working just fine. It's just that after success, it does not work anymore. Any help will be fine.

My code:

```
//..start of ajax code....
success: function(result) {
  console.log(result);
  if (result != "") {
    $("#tin").mask("000-000-000-000");
    $("#tin").val(result);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try passing value first and then mask it?

Comment: @AnandG yup, still the same, it won't mask it

Comment: what you mean by textbox ?

Comment: @bRIMOs $("#tin") is my textbox. input field.

Comment: "apprently it is not working" -why apparently? did someone tell you, or did you see something maybe that you should write in the question?

Comment: cool plugin ty :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mask plugin formats the input text when typing (exactly `oninput` event )

After setting the value with ajax the format will not be applied to this last (because of the `onchange` event not `oninput` ) .

So to workaround this just trigger the input event after setting the value using the jQuery [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function.

Like below :

```
success: function(result) {
  console.log(result);
  if (result != "") {
    $("#tin").unmask().mask("000-000-000-000");
    $("#tin").val(result).trigger("input");;
  }
}
```

You can see the Sample Fiddle example here [Link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/w8w043xL/13/)

Comment: thanks! it worked now! and also I've edited your answer. not the same from your fiddle.

Comment: great, I'm glad that it helps :)